# CONNECT BY postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there any way to write this query from oracle rdbms in postgres? 
What I care about it to have track of the iterations made(level) and to be able to iterate a particular number of times(10).

```
SELECT LEVEL 
FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `generate_series()`

```
select *
from generate_series(1,10) as t(nr)
```

Comment: Awesome, as soon as I will be able to accept this answer I will do that.

Comment: Is there any way to pass this function dynamic value. For example subquery output?

Comment: @Z.Szymon: yes, that's possible. It's a regular (set returning) function.